# How do I get timezones list using moment.js library?

Tags: momentjs

I need to make a <select> list of all actual world timezones. How do I get an array with timezones list?

Comment: take a look at http://momentjs.com/timezone/data/

Comment: Well, as far as I can understand, zone list is stored in private zoneSets variable and there is no way to get timezones list. Is this correct? And I see zone list builder, but what if zones will change by governments? I'd prefer the tzdata to be updated along with npm package. But anyway, thanks.

Comment: Not from momentjs, but here a [list](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54500197/217867).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For timezone, you should manually add timezone JS file made by yourself.

In this [page](http://momentjs.com/timezone/data/), you can pick the zones up and generate a file to be loaded after you load `moment.js` first off.

You should have something like this, take a look:

```
<script src="/javascripts/modules/moment/moment-with-langs.min.js"></script>
<script src="/javascripts/modules/moment/moment-timezone.min.js"></script>
<script src="/javascripts/modules/moment/moment-timezone-data.js"></script>
```

The JS `moment-timezone-data.js` is the custom list of the timezones.

However, so far I know, MomentJS **does not** return for you a list of all timezones, because timezone can be changed as well. If you need to populate a `select` tag, I suggest you parse the timezone list manually from the link above.

Comment: The link mentioned in the answer says "coming soon". Is there a new link? Ref [link](http://momentjs.com/timezone/data/)

Comment: What does *timezone can be changed* mean?

Comment: This has changed with the recent releases. Refer below for correct answers.

Comment: link dead this is useless

Comment: I found this: https://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/#/data-formats/unpacked-format/

Answer (score 70):

First include `moment-timezone` with data and then you can use [`moment.tz.names();`](https://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/#/using-timezones/getting-zone-names/)

Comment: Not work to me :-(  I use version 2.1.0, it look like moments.tz is undefined. Any idea?

Comment: "To use moment-timezone, you will need moment@2.6.0+, moment-timezone.js, and the moment-timezone data." http://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/#/using-timezones/

Comment: moment.tz.names() only shows currently loaded timezones, not all of them

Answer (score 32):

```
var timeZones = moment.tz.names();
```

See http://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/#/data-loading/getting-zone-names/

Comment: This only shows a list of loaded timezones, and to load timezones you have to know their names, so it's a wonderful little Catch-22

Comment: That seems to not be true anymore - the documents at that link say "To get a list of all available time zone names, use moment.tz.names."

Answer (score 13):

Beware that moment.js does not comes with moment-timezone.js by default, you have to get it.

```
bower install moment-timezone --save
npm install moment-timezone --save
Install-Package Moment.Timezone.js
```

Or [Downlaod](https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment-timezone.js)

**Then you can require an array of timezones in this way:**

```
var timezones = moment.tz.names();
```

Another useful trick is that you can set(guess) the current user timezone, so you don't have to make the user look for his timezone in a huge list, or you can set a timezone by default and then let the user change it if he needs it.

```
var currentUserTimezone = moment.tz.guess();
```

Also, you can get abbreviation of timezones if you need them, in case you have to provide and array of abbreviations of timezones:

```
moment.tz('America/Los_Angeles').format('z') //PDT
```

[moment-timezone.js full documentation](https://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/)

Comment: guess function helped me

Comment: moment.tz.names() worked when I also imported moment-timezone-with-data :)

Answer (score 7):

There are 378 timezones. A timezone is any combination of rules about time, including DST, that was in effect for any period of time, in any locale, no matter how tiny--such as an individual town in Indiana that decided to go off daylight savings time for two years in the 1940s. Or, to take a more recent example, the North Korean time zone, which was just moved up by 30 minutes. Or a dozen time zones just for Antarctica.

I doubt if you want to show all these timezones in your pulldown. You need to choose the most common 50-100 or so. You can either do that by yourself, or you can copy the list from some site like Google. You probably want to choose at least one timezone from each of the 24 offsets, so no matter where a person is, they can find one that sort of matches.

Comment: While this answer is informative, it doesnt address the questions requirements of using the moment.js library.

Comment: Some pages you would definitely want to include all available timezones. I've found a typeahead works well since most users can find their tz by searching for part of the name.

Answer (score 6):

Include [moment-timezone.js](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/moment-timezone) from cdn.

Now, use `moment.tz._names` to get the timezones as an object.
The method `moment.tz.names()` also gives the timezones as an array, but its slower.

Versions prior to 0.4.0, don't have the `moment.tz._names` object hence `moment.tz.names()` method must be used.

Comment: Thanks for this.  It led me to finding I can use moment.tz._zones to get a list of the zone objects!

Answer (score 3):

Use `moment-timezone` package not regular `moment` package.

`npm i moment-timezone` [npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/moment-timezone) and [docs](https://momentjs.com/timezone/)

```
const moment = require('moment-timezone');
const timeZones = moment.tz.names();
console.log(timeZones);
```

If just want to copy all the result:

```
["Africa/Abidjan","Africa/Accra","Africa/Addis_Ababa","Africa/Algiers","Africa/Asmara","Africa/Asmera","Africa/Bamako","Africa/Bangui","Africa/Banjul","Africa/Bissau","Africa/Blantyre","Africa/Brazzaville","Africa/Bujumbura","Africa/Cairo","Africa/Casablanca","Africa/Ceuta","Africa/Conakry","Africa/Dakar","Africa/Dar_es_Salaam","Africa/Djibouti","Africa/Douala","Africa/El_Aaiun","Africa/Freetown","Africa/Gaborone","Africa/Harare","Africa/Johannesburg","Africa/Juba","Africa/Kampala","Africa/Khartoum","Africa/Kigali","Africa/Kinshasa","Africa/Lagos","Africa/Libreville","Africa/Lome","Africa/Luanda","Africa/Lubumbashi","Africa/Lusaka","Africa/Malabo","Africa/Maputo","Africa/Maseru","Africa/Mbabane","Africa/Mogadishu","Africa/Monrovia","Africa/Nairobi","Africa/Ndjamena","Africa/Niamey","Africa/Nouakchott","Africa/Ouagadougou","Africa/Porto-Novo","Africa/Sao_Tome","Africa/Timbuktu","Africa/Tripoli","Africa/Tunis","Africa/Windhoek","America/Adak","America/Anchorage","America/Anguilla","America/Antigua","America/Araguaina","America/Argentina/Buenos_Aires","America/Argentina/Catamarca","America/Argentina/ComodRivadavia","America/Argentina/Cordoba","America/Argentina/Jujuy","America/Argentina/La_Rioja","America/Argentina/Mendoza","America/Argentina/Rio_Gallegos","America/Argentina/Salta","America/Argentina/San_Juan","America/Argentina/San_Luis","America/Argentina/Tucuman","America/Argentina/Ushuaia","America/Aruba","America/Asuncion","America/Atikokan","America/Atka","America/Bahia","America/Bahia_Banderas","America/Barbados","America/Belem","America/Belize","America/Blanc-Sablon","America/Boa_Vista","America/Bogota","America/Boise","America/Buenos_Aires","America/Cambridge_Bay","America/Campo_Grande","America/Cancun","America/Caracas","America/Catamarca","America/Cayenne","America/Cayman","America/Chicago","America/Chihuahua","America/Coral_Harbour","America/Cordoba","America/Costa_Rica","America/Creston","America/Cuiaba","America/Curacao","America/Danmarkshavn","America/Dawson","America/Dawson_Creek","America/Denver","America/Detroit","America/Dominica","America/Edmonton","America/Eirunepe","America/El_Salvador","America/Ensenada","America/Fort_Nelson","America/Fort_Wayne","America/Fortaleza","America/Glace_Bay","America/Godthab","America/Goose_Bay","America/Grand_Turk","America/Grenada","America/Guadeloupe","America/Guatemala","America/Guayaquil","America/Guyana","America/Halifax","America/Havana","America/Hermosillo","America/Indiana/Indianapolis","America/Indiana/Knox","America/Indiana/Marengo","America/Indiana/Petersburg","America/Indiana/Tell_City","America/Indiana/Vevay","America/Indiana/Vincennes","America/Indiana/Winamac","America/Indianapolis","America/Inuvik","America/Iqaluit","America/Jamaica","America/Jujuy","America/Juneau","America/Kentucky/Louisville","America/Kentucky/Monticello","America/Knox_IN","America/Kralendijk","America/La_Paz","America/Lima","America/Los_Angeles","America/Louisville","America/Lower_Princes","America/Maceio","America/Managua","America/Manaus","America/Marigot","America/Martinique","America/Matamoros","America/Mazatlan","America/Mendoza","America/Menominee","America/Merida","America/Metlakatla","America/Mexico_City","America/Miquelon","America/Moncton","America/Monterrey","America/Montevideo","America/Montreal","America/Montserrat","America/Nassau","America/New_York","America/Nipigon","America/Nome","America/Noronha","America/North_Dakota/Beulah","America/North_Dakota/Center","America/North_Dakota/New_Salem","America/Nuuk","America/Ojinaga","America/Panama","America/Pangnirtung","America/Paramaribo","America/Phoenix","America/Port-au-Prince","America/Port_of_Spain","America/Porto_Acre","America/Porto_Velho","America/Puerto_Rico","America/Punta_Arenas","America/Rainy_River","America/Rankin_Inlet","America/Recife","America/Regina","America/Resolute","America/Rio_Branco","America/Rosario","America/Santa_Isabel","America/Santarem","America/Santiago","America/Santo_Domingo","America/Sao_Paulo","America/Scoresbysund","America/Shiprock","America/Sitka","America/St_Barthelemy","America/St_Johns","America/St_Kitts","America/St_Lucia","America/St_Thomas","America/St_Vincent","America/Swift_Current","America/Tegucigalpa","America/Thule","America/Thunder_Bay","America/Tijuana","America/Toronto","America/Tortola","America/Vancouver","America/Virgin","America/Whitehorse","America/Winnipeg","America/Yakutat","America/Yellowknife","Antarctica/Casey","Antarctica/Davis","Antarctica/DumontDUrville","Antarctica/Macquarie","Antarctica/Mawson","Antarctica/McMurdo","Antarctica/Palmer","Antarctica/Rothera","Antarctica/South_Pole","Antarctica/Syowa","Antarctica/Troll","Antarctica/Vostok","Arctic/Longyearbyen","Asia/Aden","Asia/Almaty","Asia/Amman","Asia/Anadyr","Asia/Aqtau","Asia/Aqtobe","Asia/Ashgabat","Asia/Ashkhabad","Asia/Atyrau","Asia/Baghdad","Asia/Bahrain","Asia/Baku","Asia/Bangkok","Asia/Barnaul","Asia/Beirut","Asia/Bishkek","Asia/Brunei","Asia/Calcutta","Asia/Chita","Asia/Choibalsan","Asia/Chongqing","Asia/Chungking","Asia/Colombo","Asia/Dacca","Asia/Damascus","Asia/Dhaka","Asia/Dili","Asia/Dubai","Asia/Dushanbe","Asia/Famagusta","Asia/Gaza","Asia/Harbin","Asia/Hebron","Asia/Ho_Chi_Minh","Asia/Hong_Kong","Asia/Hovd","Asia/Irkutsk","Asia/Istanbul","Asia/Jakarta","Asia/Jayapura","Asia/Jerusalem","Asia/Kabul","Asia/Kamchatka","Asia/Karachi","Asia/Kashgar","Asia/Kathmandu","Asia/Katmandu","Asia/Khandyga","Asia/Kolkata","Asia/Krasnoyarsk","Asia/Kuala_Lumpur","Asia/Kuching","Asia/Kuwait","Asia/Macao","Asia/Macau","Asia/Magadan","Asia/Makassar","Asia/Manila","Asia/Muscat","Asia/Nicosia","Asia/Novokuznetsk","Asia/Novosibirsk","Asia/Omsk","Asia/Oral","Asia/Phnom_Penh","Asia/Pontianak","Asia/Pyongyang","Asia/Qatar","Asia/Qostanay","Asia/Qyzylorda","Asia/Rangoon","Asia/Riyadh","Asia/Saigon","Asia/Sakhalin","Asia/Samarkand","Asia/Seoul","Asia/Shanghai","Asia/Singapore","Asia/Srednekolymsk","Asia/Taipei","Asia/Tashkent","Asia/Tbilisi","Asia/Tehran","Asia/Tel_Aviv","Asia/Thimbu","Asia/Thimphu","Asia/Tokyo","Asia/Tomsk","Asia/Ujung_Pandang","Asia/Ulaanbaatar","Asia/Ulan_Bator","Asia/Urumqi","Asia/Ust-Nera","Asia/Vientiane","Asia/Vladivostok","Asia/Yakutsk","Asia/Yangon","Asia/Yekaterinburg","Asia/Yerevan","Atlantic/Azores","Atlantic/Bermuda","Atlantic/Canary","Atlantic/Cape_Verde","Atlantic/Faeroe","Atlantic/Faroe","Atlantic/Jan_Mayen","Atlantic/Madeira","Atlantic/Reykjavik","Atlantic/South_Georgia","Atlantic/St_Helena","Atlantic/Stanley","Australia/ACT","Australia/Adelaide","Australia/Brisbane","Australia/Broken_Hill","Australia/Canberra","Australia/Currie","Australia/Darwin","Australia/Eucla","Australia/Hobart","Australia/LHI","Australia/Lindeman","Australia/Lord_Howe","Australia/Melbourne","Australia/NSW","Australia/North","Australia/Perth","Australia/Queensland","Australia/South","Australia/Sydney","Australia/Tasmania","Australia/Victoria","Australia/West","Australia/Yancowinna","Brazil/Acre","Brazil/DeNoronha","Brazil/East","Brazil/West","CET","CST6CDT","Canada/Atlantic","Canada/Central","Canada/Eastern","Canada/Mountain","Canada/Newfoundland","Canada/Pacific","Canada/Saskatchewan","Canada/Yukon","Chile/Continental","Chile/EasterIsland","Cuba","EET","EST","EST5EDT","Egypt","Eire","Etc/GMT","Etc/GMT+0","Etc/GMT+1","Etc/GMT+10","Etc/GMT+11","Etc/GMT+12","Etc/GMT+2","Etc/GMT+3","Etc/GMT+4","Etc/GMT+5","Etc/GMT+6","Etc/GMT+7","Etc/GMT+8","Etc/GMT+9","Etc/GMT-0","Etc/GMT-1","Etc/GMT-10","Etc/GMT-11","Etc/GMT-12","Etc/GMT-13","Etc/GMT-14","Etc/GMT-2","Etc/GMT-3","Etc/GMT-4","Etc/GMT-5","Etc/GMT-6","Etc/GMT-7","Etc/GMT-8","Etc/GMT-9","Etc/GMT0","Etc/Greenwich","Etc/UCT","Etc/UTC","Etc/Universal","Etc/Zulu","Europe/Amsterdam","Europe/Andorra","Europe/Astrakhan","Europe/Athens","Europe/Belfast","Europe/Belgrade","Europe/Berlin","Europe/Bratislava","Europe/Brussels","Europe/Bucharest","Europe/Budapest","Europe/Busingen","Europe/Chisinau","Europe/Copenhagen","Europe/Dublin","Europe/Gibraltar","Europe/Guernsey","Europe/Helsinki","Europe/Isle_of_Man","Europe/Istanbul","Europe/Jersey","Europe/Kaliningrad","Europe/Kiev","Europe/Kirov","Europe/Lisbon","Europe/Ljubljana","Europe/London","Europe/Luxembourg","Europe/Madrid","Europe/Malta","Europe/Mariehamn","Europe/Minsk","Europe/Monaco","Europe/Moscow","Europe/Nicosia","Europe/Oslo","Europe/Paris","Europe/Podgorica","Europe/Prague","Europe/Riga","Europe/Rome","Europe/Samara","Europe/San_Marino","Europe/Sarajevo","Europe/Saratov","Europe/Simferopol","Europe/Skopje","Europe/Sofia","Europe/Stockholm","Europe/Tallinn","Europe/Tirane","Europe/Tiraspol","Europe/Ulyanovsk","Europe/Uzhgorod","Europe/Vaduz","Europe/Vatican","Europe/Vienna","Europe/Vilnius","Europe/Volgograd","Europe/Warsaw","Europe/Zagreb","Europe/Zaporozhye","Europe/Zurich","GB","GB-Eire","GMT","GMT+0","GMT-0","GMT0","Greenwich","HST","Hongkong","Iceland","Indian/Antananarivo","Indian/Chagos","Indian/Christmas","Indian/Cocos","Indian/Comoro","Indian/Kerguelen","Indian/Mahe","Indian/Maldives","Indian/Mauritius","Indian/Mayotte","Indian/Reunion","Iran","Israel","Jamaica","Japan","Kwajalein","Libya","MET","MST","MST7MDT","Mexico/BajaNorte","Mexico/BajaSur","Mexico/General","NZ","NZ-CHAT","Navajo","PRC","PST8PDT","Pacific/Apia","Pacific/Auckland","Pacific/Bougainville","Pacific/Chatham","Pacific/Chuuk","Pacific/Easter","Pacific/Efate","Pacific/Enderbury","Pacific/Fakaofo","Pacific/Fiji","Pacific/Funafuti","Pacific/Galapagos","Pacific/Gambier","Pacific/Guadalcanal","Pacific/Guam","Pacific/Honolulu","Pacific/Johnston","Pacific/Kiritimati","Pacific/Kosrae","Pacific/Kwajalein","Pacific/Majuro","Pacific/Marquesas","Pacific/Midway","Pacific/Nauru","Pacific/Niue","Pacific/Norfolk","Pacific/Noumea","Pacific/Pago_Pago","Pacific/Palau","Pacific/Pitcairn","Pacific/Pohnpei","Pacific/Ponape","Pacific/Port_Moresby","Pacific/Rarotonga","Pacific/Saipan","Pacific/Samoa","Pacific/Tahiti","Pacific/Tarawa","Pacific/Tongatapu","Pacific/Truk","Pacific/Wake","Pacific/Wallis","Pacific/Yap","Poland","Portugal","ROC","ROK","Singapore","Turkey","UCT","US/Alaska","US/Aleutian","US/Arizona","US/Central","US/East-Indiana","US/Eastern","US/Hawaii","US/Indiana-Starke","US/Michigan","US/Mountain","US/Pacific","US/Samoa","UTC","Universal","W-SU","WET","Zulu"]
```

It is also nice UX to offer good default, to guess user's timezone from user's device settings use built in function:

`moment.tz.guess();`

Comment: But you might know moment js is in maintenance mode and should choose a different package.

Comment: it's in maintenance mode yet a lot of people still use it for many reason. Anyone building anything new, should check https://moment.github.io/luxon/#/

Answer (score 1):

You can save a script `importTimezones.mjs` with this content:

```
import moment from "moment-timezone"

const timeZones = moment.tz.names();

for (const timezone of timeZones) {
  console.log(timezone)
}
```

If you run this with `node importTimezones.mjs` you will see all timezones being printed on the console.