# Invalid time zone specified: US/Alaska, US/Arizona, US/Mountain, US/Central etc error in Chrome but working in Mozilla

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, timezone, ecmascript-intl

I am trying to convert timestamp in to various time zone's local time and found certain TimeZone are not supporting in Chrome (v76.0.38) but working fine in Mozilla (v68.0.2).

```
  let d = new Date(1567083463);
  let n = d.toLocaleString('en-GB', { timeZone: "US/Arizona" });
```

> Uncaught RangeError: Invalid time zone specified: US/Arizona
>
> at Date.toLocaleString ()

Several other timezones are also throwing the same error

`US/Alaska`
`US/Mountain`
`US/Central`
`US/East-Indiana`

Comment: That website is *not* the list of timezones supported *by Chrome*…!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

That page describes timezones supported by *another google product*, **not Chrome**.

Referring to [MDN's documentation on `toLocaleString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleString):

> **timeZone**
>   The time zone to use. The only value implementations must recognize is "UTC"; the default is the runtime's default time zone. Implementations may also recognize the time zone names of the [IANA time zone database](https://www.iana.org/time-zones), such as "Asia/Shanghai", "Asia/Kolkata", "America/New_York".

Valid time zones can be found at that IANA link, or you can use [Wikipedia: List of tz database time zones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones).  You'll notice that all of the "US/*" timezones are *deprecated*.  Use only *Canonical* entries from the Wikipedia page, such as:

- America/New_York
- America/Denver
- America/Chicago

etc.

Comment: They are deprecated from the perspective that there is a prefered newer form.  But even this is opinionated (I was actually the one to add that column to the Wikipedia page).  They should all still work. There's something else going on here, as *some* of the older "deprecated" style still work in Chrome and others do not.  A few examples, `"Canada/Pacific"`, `"Australia/Queensland"`, `"Mexico/General"`, and `"Iran"` work in Chrome, but `"Australia/ACT"`, `"Mexico/BajaNorte"`, and `"GB-Eire"` do not.

Comment: @MattJohnson-Pint Because `"Mexico/BajaNorte"` and others are the *old* names for regions, and they've been deprecated by the IANA.  http://ftp.iana.org/tz/tzdb-2016g/backward .  Wikipedia shouldn't be taken as the canonical source, only a convenient lookup.  Ultimately the IANA data should be consulted.

Comment: @MattJohnson-Pint As well, the spec only says that UTC must be supported; it makes no mention of any other time zones, or lists thereof, being supported.  Ultimately its up to individual implementations.  Still, I wouldn't expect a TZ that has been deprecated by the IANA to work.

Comment: Thanks I have changed the names but its confusing to see it working properly in Mozilla not in chrome

Comment: The spec does not specify what times zones should be supported.  It is left up to individual implementations.

Comment: Actually, EMCA 402, 6th edition, section 6.4 "Time Zone Names" says: "All registered Zone and Link names are allowed. Implementations must recognize all such names...".  Thus, it seems Chromium is not currently following the spec.

Comment: Chromium bug: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=364374

Comment: For what it's worth, I've had "US/Mountain" in my app and it worked fine on iOS, Samsung, Huawei and some other devices, but not on Pixel 2