# How to change Moment.js Timezone defaults?

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-app-engine, momentjs

I am running an node js - express api using moment.js.
My current TZ-Location is Europe/Berlin.(local)
I had a inkonsistent state between my develop environment(local) and my production environment.
While using the moment library in develop/local environment ive got an utc offset of 120min. But the Google Cloud standard AppEngine doesnt have an offset. So I get a date, which is 2h lower than needed.
I was seaching for a while but dont found the right answer to set the local timezone or a local offset for the appengine to work with.

Does someone know, how to fix this problem globaly without changing all date-parsing statements? --> moment()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to set the timezone globally for moment you can do that by

```
const moment = require('moment-timezone')

moment.tz.setDefault('Europe/Berlin')
```

https://momentjscom.readthedocs.io/en/latest/moment/03-manipulating/09-utc-offset/

Comment: i've tried that with the moment-timezone plugin, but it doesnt worked

Comment: Interesting. Well I'd advise storing timestamps in unix time and converting to your timezone.

Comment: do i have to update all required statements in the js files?

Comment: I've added to app.js:
var moment = require('moment-timezone');
moment.tz.setDefault('Europe/Berlin');

// Now I see the required offset
console.log(moment())
console.log(moment().format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss"))
console.log(moment().utcOffset())
console.log(new Date())

//While parsing sth from a DB
Thu Apr 09 2020 09:24:58 GMT+0200 (GMT+02:00)
It will still  output 2h to much in the moment(Thu Apr 09 2020 09:24:58 GMT+0200 (GMT+02:00)).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss')

Answer (score 1):

You can use global instance and change tz using `moment.tz`

More: https://momentjscom.readthedocs.io/en/latest/moment-timezone/01-using-timezones/05-default-timezone/

```
moment.tz.setDefault("Europe/Berlin");
```

Also can see list of TZ:

[How to get list of all timezones in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38399465/how-to-get-list-of-all-timezones-in-javascript/54500197#54500197)