# Two apps script projects outputting different toLocaleTimeString() (en-US PT & Eastern)

Tags: javascript, datetime, google-apps-script

I'm working on a timesheet for my office and I've ran into the last problem I'd expect; the locale in one sheet (used for the business's main operations) is different than the locale in the other (going to be used for clocking in and out).

I know how to get the correct time output despite the problem, but I don't know why it's a problem in the first place.

None of the code in my first sheet (the correct locale) is relevant; that project has little to do with time and date.

The code for my second sheet is doing a few things:

1. Use the start day & end day of a week to determine which sheet to use in the spreadsheet (sheets are split into weeks)
2. get the current date & user's name to determine the position of the clock-in time input

Pretty simple

So far I've tried using [options](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleTimeString#using_options) to set the timezone to PT, but no luck & I can't think of anything else that would affect my locale.

Also, my computer and my sheet are both set to PT.

Relevant code:

```
const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
const ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
var index;

const dates = {
  'Today': Date.now(),
  'Feb20': Date.parse('2022-Feb-20'),
  'Feb26': Date.parse('2022-Feb-26'),
  'Feb27': Date.parse('2022-Feb-27'),
  'Mar05': Date.parse('2022-Mar-05'),
  'Mar06': Date.parse('2022-Mar-06'),
  'Mar12': Date.parse('2022-Mar-12'),
  'Mar13': Date.parse('2022-Mar-13'),
  'Mar19': Date.parse('2022-Mar-19')
}

if (dates.Feb20 < dates.Today && dates.Today < dates.Feb26) {
  index = 0;
} else if (dates.Feb27 < dates.Today && dates.Today < dates.Mar05) {
  index = 1;
} else if (dates.Mar06 < dates.Today && dates.Today < dates.Mar12) {
  index = 2;
} else if (dates.Mar13 < dates.Today && dates.Today < dates.Mar19) {
  index = 3;
} 

const sheet = ss.getSheets()[index];

const nameColumn = sheet.getRange(2, 1, 12, 1);
const dateRow = sheet.getRange(1, 2, 1, 7);

const dateOptions = {
  year: 'numeric', month: 'short', day: 'numeric', timezone: 'America/Los_Angeles'
}

const timeOptions = {
  hour: 'numeric', minute: 'numeric', second: 'numeric', timezone: 'America/Los_Angeles', hour12: false
}

function clockIn() {
  const date = new Date();
  const formattedDate = date.toLocaleDateString('en-US', dateOptions).replace(',', '').split(' ');
  Logger.log(date);
  const employeeName = ui.prompt('Enter your name: ', '', ui.ButtonSet.OK).getResponseText();
  const row = nameColumn.createTextFinder(employeeName).matchEntireCell(false).findNext().getRow() + 1;
  const col = dateRow.createTextFinder(formattedDate[2] + ' ' + formattedDate[0] + ' ' + formattedDate[1]).matchEntireCell(true).findNext().getColumn();
  sheet.getRange(row, col).setValue(new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-US', timeOptions).format(date));
}
```

[image: Test function to display the issue. The left log is correct.]

Comment: Set timezone in manifest ``appscript.json`` file.

Comment: Or in the spreadsheet settings.

Comment: Note that the result of `Date.parse('2022-Feb-20')` is implementation dependent. In Safari it produces an invalid date, see [*Why does Date.parse give incorrect results?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587345/why-does-date-parse-give-incorrect-results)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was solved by the first comment.

To fix this issue, first check the following box in Apps Script Project Settings:

> Show "appsscript.json" manifest file in editor

Then just update the "timezone" object literal to whichever timezone you're working with.

Here is a [list of timezones](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38399465/how-to-get-list-of-all-timezones-in-javascript)