# List of timezones with cities

Tags: angular, typescript, angular8

I'm trying to display the dropdown list of timezones with few cities each timezone like:

- UTC +1 Amsterdam, Berlin
- UTC +2 Athens, Bucharest
- UTC +3 Kuwait, Baghdad

However for example Amsterdam during the winter is UTC +1, but in the summer UTC +2.
Some countries have winter/summer time, some haven't.

Is there any way to handle it by angular 8 or it must be sent to frontend by backend?

Expected case:
User clicks on dropdown list and see Amsterdam as UTC +2 or UTC +1 depending on current date.

Comment: I would suggest your backend API sent you the list, so that it is aware of DST.

Comment: Do you have the list of cities? You can have a fairly small file built in if you're wanting to avoid making api calls, or you need your app to work offline.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a list of cities you can use something like the following if you need your app to work offline. You'll want to modify the following list to the cities you need in your dropdown.

Instead of

```
 'Europe/Berlin'
```

you may want

```
 //time zone name, your custom name
 '["Europe/Berlin", "Amsterdam, Berlin"]
```

and then in the loop you would use

```
let tzDate = new Date(date.toLocaleString('en-US', { timeZone: timeZone[0] })
```

to specify the timezone and `timezone[1]` for the custom cities you're trying to include.

What the following does it iterate through the time zones and calculates the offset based on the current time, which should reflect daylight savings and other modifications so long as the runtime environment is up to date (which I can't promise).

```
var aryIannaTimeZones = [
  'Europe/Andorra',
  'Asia/Dubai',
  'Asia/Kabul',
  'Europe/Tirane',
  'Asia/Yerevan',
  'Antarctica/Casey',
  'Antarctica/Davis',
  'Antarctica/DumontDUrville', // https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=928068
  'Antarctica/Mawson',
  'Antarctica/Palmer',
  'Antarctica/Rothera',
  'Antarctica/Syowa',
  'Antarctica/Troll',
  'Antarctica/Vostok',
  'America/Argentina/Buenos_Aires',
  'America/Argentina/Cordoba',
  'America/Argentina/Salta',
  'America/Argentina/Jujuy',
  'America/Argentina/Tucuman',
  'America/Argentina/Catamarca',
  'America/Argentina/La_Rioja',
  'America/Argentina/San_Juan',
  'America/Argentina/Mendoza',
  'America/Argentina/San_Luis',
  'America/Argentina/Rio_Gallegos',
  'America/Argentina/Ushuaia',
  'Pacific/Pago_Pago',
  'Europe/Vienna',
  'Australia/Lord_Howe',
  'Antarctica/Macquarie',
  'Australia/Hobart',
  'Australia/Currie',
  'Australia/Melbourne',
  'Australia/Sydney',
  'Australia/Broken_Hill',
  'Australia/Brisbane',
  'Australia/Lindeman',
  'Australia/Adelaide',
  'Australia/Darwin',
  'Australia/Perth',
  'Australia/Eucla',
  'Asia/Baku',
  'America/Barbados',
  'Asia/Dhaka',
  'Europe/Brussels',
  'Europe/Sofia',
  'Atlantic/Bermuda',
  'Asia/Brunei',
  'America/La_Paz',
  'America/Noronha',
  'America/Belem',
  'America/Fortaleza',
  'America/Recife',
  'America/Araguaina',
  'America/Maceio',
  'America/Bahia',
  'America/Sao_Paulo',
  'America/Campo_Grande',
  'America/Cuiaba',
  'America/Santarem',
  'America/Porto_Velho',
  'America/Boa_Vista',
  'America/Manaus',
  'America/Eirunepe',
  'America/Rio_Branco',
  'America/Nassau',
  'Asia/Thimphu',
  'Europe/Minsk',
  'America/Belize',
  'America/St_Johns',
  'America/Halifax',
  'America/Glace_Bay',
  'America/Moncton',
  'America/Goose_Bay',
  'America/Blanc-Sablon',
  'America/Toronto',
  'America/Nipigon',
  'America/Thunder_Bay',
  'America/Iqaluit',
  'America/Pangnirtung',
  'America/Atikokan',
  'America/Winnipeg',
  'America/Rainy_River',
  'America/Resolute',
  'America/Rankin_Inlet',
  'America/Regina',
  'America/Swift_Current',
  'America/Edmonton',
  'America/Cambridge_Bay',
  'America/Yellowknife',
  'America/Inuvik',
  'America/Creston',
  'America/Dawson_Creek',
  'America/Fort_Nelson',
  'America/Vancouver',
  'America/Whitehorse',
  'America/Dawson',
  'Indian/Cocos',
  'Europe/Zurich',
  'Africa/Abidjan',
  'Pacific/Rarotonga',
  'America/Santiago',
  'America/Punta_Arenas',
  'Pacific/Easter',
  'Asia/Shanghai',
  'Asia/Urumqi',
  'America/Bogota',
  'America/Costa_Rica',
  'America/Havana',
  'Atlantic/Cape_Verde',
  'America/Curacao',
  'Indian/Christmas',
  'Asia/Nicosia',
  'Asia/Famagusta',
  'Europe/Prague',
  'Europe/Berlin',
  'Europe/Copenhagen',
  'America/Santo_Domingo',
  'Africa/Algiers',
  'America/Guayaquil',
  'Pacific/Galapagos',
  'Europe/Tallinn',
  'Africa/Cairo',
  'Africa/El_Aaiun',
  'Europe/Madrid',
  'Africa/Ceuta',
  'Atlantic/Canary',
  'Europe/Helsinki',
  'Pacific/Fiji',
  'Atlantic/Stanley',
  'Pacific/Chuuk',
  'Pacific/Pohnpei',
  'Pacific/Kosrae',
  'Atlantic/Faroe',
  'Europe/Paris',
  'Europe/London',
  'Asia/Tbilisi',
  'America/Cayenne',
  'Africa/Accra',
  'Europe/Gibraltar',
  'America/Godthab',
  'America/Danmarkshavn',
  'America/Scoresbysund',
  'America/Thule',
  'Europe/Athens',
  'Atlantic/South_Georgia',
  'America/Guatemala',
  'Pacific/Guam',
  'Africa/Bissau',
  'America/Guyana',
  'Asia/Hong_Kong',
  'America/Tegucigalpa',
  'America/Port-au-Prince',
  'Europe/Budapest',
  'Asia/Jakarta',
  'Asia/Pontianak',
  'Asia/Makassar',
  'Asia/Jayapura',
  'Europe/Dublin',
  'Asia/Jerusalem',
  'Asia/Kolkata',
  'Indian/Chagos',
  'Asia/Baghdad',
  'Asia/Tehran',
  'Atlantic/Reykjavik',
  'Europe/Rome',
  'America/Jamaica',
  'Asia/Amman',
  'Asia/Tokyo',
  'Africa/Nairobi',
  'Asia/Bishkek',
  'Pacific/Tarawa',
  'Pacific/Enderbury',
  'Pacific/Kiritimati',
  'Asia/Pyongyang',
  'Asia/Seoul',
  'Asia/Almaty',
  'Asia/Qyzylorda',
  'Asia/Qostanay', // https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=928068
  'Asia/Aqtobe',
  'Asia/Aqtau',
  'Asia/Atyrau',
  'Asia/Oral',
  'Asia/Beirut',
  'Asia/Colombo',
  'Africa/Monrovia',
  'Europe/Vilnius',
  'Europe/Luxembourg',
  'Europe/Riga',
  'Africa/Tripoli',
  'Africa/Casablanca',
  'Europe/Monaco',
  'Europe/Chisinau',
  'Pacific/Majuro',
  'Pacific/Kwajalein',
  'Asia/Yangon',
  'Asia/Ulaanbaatar',
  'Asia/Hovd',
  'Asia/Choibalsan',
  'Asia/Macau',
  'America/Martinique',
  'Europe/Malta',
  'Indian/Mauritius',
  'Indian/Maldives',
  'America/Mexico_City',
  'America/Cancun',
  'America/Merida',
  'America/Monterrey',
  'America/Matamoros',
  'America/Mazatlan',
  'America/Chihuahua',
  'America/Ojinaga',
  'America/Hermosillo',
  'America/Tijuana',
  'America/Bahia_Banderas',
  'Asia/Kuala_Lumpur',
  'Asia/Kuching',
  'Africa/Maputo',
  'Africa/Windhoek',
  'Pacific/Noumea',
  'Pacific/Norfolk',
  'Africa/Lagos',
  'America/Managua',
  'Europe/Amsterdam',
  'Europe/Oslo',
  'Asia/Kathmandu',
  'Pacific/Nauru',
  'Pacific/Niue',
  'Pacific/Auckland',
  'Pacific/Chatham',
  'America/Panama',
  'America/Lima',
  'Pacific/Tahiti',
  'Pacific/Marquesas',
  'Pacific/Gambier',
  'Pacific/Port_Moresby',
  'Pacific/Bougainville',
  'Asia/Manila',
  'Asia/Karachi',
  'Europe/Warsaw',
  'America/Miquelon',
  'Pacific/Pitcairn',
  'America/Puerto_Rico',
  'Asia/Gaza',
  'Asia/Hebron',
  'Europe/Lisbon',
  'Atlantic/Madeira',
  'Atlantic/Azores',
  'Pacific/Palau',
  'America/Asuncion',
  'Asia/Qatar',
  'Indian/Reunion',
  'Europe/Bucharest',
  'Europe/Belgrade',
  'Europe/Kaliningrad',
  'Europe/Moscow',
  'Europe/Simferopol',
  'Europe/Kirov',
  'Europe/Astrakhan',
  'Europe/Volgograd',
  'Europe/Saratov',
  'Europe/Ulyanovsk',
  'Europe/Samara',
  'Asia/Yekaterinburg',
  'Asia/Omsk',
  'Asia/Novosibirsk',
  'Asia/Barnaul',
  'Asia/Tomsk',
  'Asia/Novokuznetsk',
  'Asia/Krasnoyarsk',
  'Asia/Irkutsk',
  'Asia/Chita',
  'Asia/Yakutsk',
  'Asia/Khandyga',
  'Asia/Vladivostok',
  'Asia/Ust-Nera',
  'Asia/Magadan',
  'Asia/Sakhalin',
  'Asia/Srednekolymsk',
  'Asia/Kamchatka',
  'Asia/Anadyr',
  'Asia/Riyadh',
  'Pacific/Guadalcanal',
  'Indian/Mahe',
  'Africa/Khartoum',
  'Europe/Stockholm',
  'Asia/Singapore',
  'America/Paramaribo',
  'Africa/Juba',
  'Africa/Sao_Tome',
  'America/El_Salvador',
  'Asia/Damascus',
  'America/Grand_Turk',
  'Africa/Ndjamena',
  'Indian/Kerguelen',
  'Asia/Bangkok',
  'Asia/Dushanbe',
  'Pacific/Fakaofo',
  'Asia/Dili',
  'Asia/Ashgabat',
  'Africa/Tunis',
  'Pacific/Tongatapu',
  'Europe/Istanbul',
  'America/Port_of_Spain',
  'Pacific/Funafuti',
  'Asia/Taipei',
  'Europe/Kiev',
  'Europe/Uzhgorod',
  'Europe/Zaporozhye',
  'Pacific/Wake',
  'America/New_York',
  'America/Detroit',
  'America/Kentucky/Louisville',
  'America/Kentucky/Monticello',
  'America/Indiana/Indianapolis',
  'America/Indiana/Vincennes',
  'America/Indiana/Winamac',
  'America/Indiana/Marengo',
  'America/Indiana/Petersburg',
  'America/Indiana/Vevay',
  'America/Chicago',
  'America/Indiana/Tell_City',
  'America/Indiana/Knox',
  'America/Menominee',
  'America/North_Dakota/Center',
  'America/North_Dakota/New_Salem',
  'America/North_Dakota/Beulah',
  'America/Denver',
  'America/Boise',
  'America/Phoenix',
  'America/Los_Angeles',
  'America/Anchorage',
  'America/Juneau',
  'America/Sitka',
  'America/Metlakatla',
  'America/Yakutat',
  'America/Nome',
  'America/Adak',
  'Pacific/Honolulu',
  'America/Montevideo',
  'Asia/Samarkand',
  'Asia/Tashkent',
  'America/Caracas',
  'Asia/Ho_Chi_Minh',
  'Pacific/Efate',
  'Pacific/Wallis',
  'Pacific/Apia',
  'Africa/Johannesburg'
];

let date = new Date;
aryIannaTimeZones.forEach((timeZone) =>{
  let utcDate = new Date(date.toLocaleString('en-US', { timeZone: "UTC" }));
  let tzDate = new Date(date.toLocaleString('en-US', { timeZone: timeZone }));
  let offset = utcDate.getTime() - tzDate.getTime();

  console.log(timeZone,"UTC offset: " + offset/3600000);
});
```

This answer was pieced together from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38399465/how-to-get-list-of-all-timezones-in-javascript) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15141762/how-to-initialize-a-javascript-date-to-a-particular-time-zone)

Comment: which function are you referring to? The one in [javascript](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_gettimezoneoffset.asp) does not take any arguments. After the user clicks the timezone name in dropdown, the client browser should determine if that selected IANA `timezone` is observing DST right now or not. Your solution doesn't seem to address that.

Comment: @Anand Sowmithiran. You're right. I'm not sure why I thought that I could pass the timezone code and get a result. Just a moment while I either delete or fix my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I found this [API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/timezone/overview) from google. However it costs, so either you get your boss to spend a little (:P) or just use it for the transfer while writing your own API.