# How to get "forEach" output values into html

Tags: javascript, foreach

I have tried coding a JS world clock.
The world clock itself is posted on stackoverflow.com but I do not know how to get output values from "forEach" into html properly.
Would anyone tell me the correct coding or reference sites?
Thank you.

Ref. How to get list of all timezones in javascript
[How to get list of all timezones in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38399465/how-to-get-list-of-all-timezones-in-javascript)

JS code below works but it is just my guesswork.(JS beginner)

```js
setInterval(() => {
  let out = "";
  const city = ['Asia/Taipei', 'America/New_York'];

  city.forEach(adjustTime);

  function adjustTime(item) {
    const today = new Date();
    const localTime = today.toLocaleString("ja-JP", {
      timeZone: `${item}`
    });

    out += item + localTime + "<br>";
    document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = out;

  }
}, 1000);
```

```html
<p id="output"></p>
```

Comment: Place the `innerHTML` line outside of the function.

Comment: What is the issue. The clock seems to work as designed

Comment: If you want a space: `out += \`${item} : ${localTime}<br>\``

Comment: I would like know the correct coding.It workes but I do not know why!
I add 'let out = "";' and 'out += item + localTime + "<br>";' to get html output, but I do not know if the coding correct.  Thank you for commenting.

Answer (score 0):

Your code works. It can be improved. For example like this

I am using

- [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)
- [Array.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

```js
const city = ['Asia/Taipei', 'America/New_York'];
const adjustTime = item => {
  const today = new Date();
  const localTime = today.toLocaleString("ja-JP", {
    timeZone: `${item}`
  });
  return `${item}: ${localTime}`;
};
const out = document.getElementById("output");

setInterval(() => {
  out.innerHTML = city.map(adjustTime).join("<br>");
}, 1000);
```

```html
<p id="output"></p>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your work! I have tried it out and it worked.
It looks cool!(I couldn't do that but I could learn from it.)

Comment: I added the tech I used