# Intl.supportedValuesOf polyfill for React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I was using `Intl.supportedValuesOf` however, I noticed a fewer list of browsers that support it.

I searched on NPM for a Polyfill but could not find anything.

Is there a good solution to get the list of timezone?

[image]

Comment: try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38399465/how-to-get-list-of-all-timezones-in-javascript

Comment: Seems like a generic polyfill would not be useful; the whole point of the API is to provide the details *for a particular implementation*. Thus, the polyfill would need to know the correct (if not necessarily complete) response for a platform that doesn't already support the real API.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get list of all timezones in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38399465/how-to-get-list-of-all-timezones-in-javascript)