# How to get timezone name list using dayJs

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, momentjs, dayjs

I was recently using momentjs but just switched to dayjs. However, I need to get a list of timezones. With momentjs it was pretty simple : `moment.tz().names()` , but with dayjs I can't figure out how to do it. I don't want to get 500+ timezone, rather I need I shorter, more compact list that taking account winter/summer hours changes.

Any Idea ?

Comment: This might give you some insight. https://github.com/iamkun/dayjs/issues/695

Comment: Or just don't rely on a library https://stackoverflow.com/q/38399465/295783 `Intl.supportedValuesOf('timeZone')`

Answer (score 2):

Use the code below in your browser console

```
 for (const timeZone of Intl.supportedValuesOf('timeZone')) {console.log(timeZone)}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Intl.supportedValuesOf('timeZone')`. This will return the name of the available time zones. This is not dayjs dependent. It can be used

```js
let timezones = Intl.supportedValuesOf("timeZone");
console.log(timezones)
```